# How to get individual array names as strings for array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
// Facility table attributes to be read in json format
String facilityName[], recApp[], recFacility[], sendApp[], 
       sendFacility[], enable[], doneness[], retryLimit[], 
       watchDelay[], retryDelay[], ackTimeout[], 
       keepConOpen[], sendTimeout[], cleanupDelay[], 
       host[], port[];

String facilityTableAttrs[][] = new String[][] { 
       facilityName, recApp, recFacility, sendApp, 
       sendFacility, enable, doneness, retryLimit, 
       watchDelay, retryDelay, ackTimeout, keepConOpen, 
       sendTimeout, cleanupDelay, host, port};
```

I have array of arrays called facilityTableAttrs declared as above.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is it possible to do the above array declaration in a single step ?

2) I wish to get the individual array names of these 1D array using something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < facilityTableAttrs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(facilityTableAttrs[i].toString());
}
```

but it fails. How to get the individual array names as string?

Comment: variable names should start with a lower case character, so 'facilityName' instead of 'FacilityName'. Also it is more common to do 'String[][] facilityTableAttrs' than 'String facilityTableAttrs[][]' (which is also correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first list of arrays you declare don't seem to be initialized anywhere.

As such they are `null`, and invoking `toString` on any of them will cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown, hence "it fails".

By the way, invoking `toString` on an non-null array would actually print something similar to the `Object.toString` representation, which is not what you want (`Arrays.toString(myArray)` is your friend here).

You could initialize each and every single array and populate them optionally, before adding them to the main `String[][]` but I recommend you don't.

Instead, investigate the collections framework.

What you could use here is a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Or better even, a custom object with properties such as `List<String> facilityName`, `List<String> recApp`, etc.

Finally, note the variable naming, which is **camelBack** according to [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: I can't populate them because the size is initially unknown, it will be picked up based on the values populated as json string by the user. I just need the array names like "FacilityName" "RecApp" etc.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 then I highly recommend using a custom object with a number of `List<String>` as properties, or worse but acceptable, a `Map<String, List<String>>` as indicated.

Comment: But in that case, i need to initialize each individual list, and that increases the code size, i can't have an array of list as well. Something like `List<String> facilityTableAttrs[]=new List{List<String> FacilityName, List<String>RecApp` is not allowed in Java

Comment: You will need to initialize any object you add objects to, be it an array or a `List`. You cannot initialize a `List` itself, it's an interface. You probably want `ArrayList` as your concrete class. As I already said, you're better of with a `Map<String, List<String>>` not a List<String>[].

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with arrays. You need to use map, like so:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

You need to choose correct data structure for your problem.

Arrays are used only for storing values, thay are not interestd in bounding names to them.
Maps on the other hands are great with bounding names (keys that are unique)  to any type of value.

Comment: Array os list is not allowed in Java. Initializing each attribute will icrease code size, which is the reason i wanted to use an array. Something like `List<String> facilityTableAttrs[]=new List{List<String> FacilityName, List<String>RecApp` is not allowed in Java

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use a wrapper class:

```
public class Facility {
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> values;
    public Facility(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.values = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

and then do:

```
Facility[] facilities = new Facility[] {
    new Facility("facility 1"),
    new Facility("facility 2"),
    new Facility("facility 3"),
    new Facility("facility 4"),
};
for(Facility facility : facilities) {
    System.out.println(facility.getName());
}
```

To add a value to a facility you'd do:

```
Facility facility = facilities.get(0);
facility.getValues().add("bla");
```

If you need to look up facilities by name, then use a Map instead of an array:

```
    ...
    // see createLookup method below
    Map<String, Facility> facilities = createLookup(
        new Facility("facility 1"),
        new Facility("facility 2"),
        new Facility("facility 3"),
        new Facility("facility 4"));

    // print names
    for(Facility facility : facilities.values()) {
        System.out.println(facility.getName());
    }

    // add a value
    Facility facility = facilities.get("facility 3");
    facility.getValues().add("bla");
}

private Map<String, Facility> createLookup(Facility.. facilities) {
    // use TreeMap to have sorted keys
    Map<String, Facility> lookup = new TreeMap<>();
    for(Facility facility : facilities) {
        lookup.put(facility.getName(), facility);
    }
    return lookup;
}
```